# python editors for windows 8.1

Tags: python

I'm returning to programming after many (about 15) years absence. I have chosen Python as it appears to be similar to BASIC although 'improved' with functions and Object Orientation among others.

My problem is that, having worked through programming lessons which included an editor, I loaded onto my Windows 8.1 PC a copy of Python 3.4 but the editors don't seem simple to use. I have tried several editors and the one I liked best was JetBrain's Pycharm however that is not as simple as Microsoft's Visual Basic.

I appreciate that that was a commercial environment with which I was well familiar but does anybody know of a simple editor that can be linked to Python 3.4, uses line numbers and can run in Windows 8.1?

Thanks

Comment: Define what you mean by simple editor. If you want something simple, try IDLE, the world's most ancient programming environment.

Comment: At this point, check if you've met "idle" which comes installed along Python for windows.

Comment: This question isn't really suitable for SO. But anyway, many Python beginners use IDLE, but bear in mind that IDLE has its quirks. Since you like Visual Basic you _may_ like Visual Studio, but it's not a free program (although there's a 90 day free trial). You will need to install a Python plugin, though.

Comment: You could give geany a try - it also has windows binarys and it is what I use for programming in python

Comment: Again, this is not a great question to ask here on SO. Nevertheless, I recommend looking at SublimeText.